# Calculating Time Complexity of a recursive function

Tags: time-complexity

### .0 < c < 1 ,T(n) = T(cn) + T((1 - c)n) + 1

Base level:
if(n<=1) return;
data type - positive integers

I have to find the Big-Theta function of this recursive function.
I've tried to develop the recursive equation but it gets complicated from level to level and no formation is seen.

I also tried this -
assume that c<(1-c).
so -
2T(cn) + 1 <= T(cn) + T((1-c)n)+1 <= 2T((1-c)n)+1

It gave me some lower bound and upper bound but not a theta bound :(

Comment: Instead of posting this as an image, please edit your question to include it directly as text.

Answer (score 0):

As c approaches either 0 or 1, the recursion approaches T(n) = T(n-1) + 2 (assuming that T(0) = 1 as well). This has as a solution the linear function T(n) = 2n - 1 for n > 0.

For c = 1/2, the recursion becomes T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 1. It looks like T(n) = 2n - 1 is a solution to this for n > 0.

This seems like strong evidence that the function T(n) = 2n - 1 is a solution for all c: it works on both ends and in the middle. If we sub in...

```
2n - 1 = 2cn - 1 + 2(1-c)n - 1 + 1 
       = 2cn - 1 + 2n - 2cn - 1 + 1
       = 2n - 1
```

We find that T(n) = 2n - 1 is a solution for the general case.

Comment: Well that's a cool solution. Can you explain a bit further why as c approaches 0 or 1 the recursion approaches T(n-1) +2 ? as c approaches 1 for example, cn --> n, you say its n-1 because the function deals with positive integers only? so it is rounded to n-1.

Comment: As c approaches 1, cn approaches n, but due to integer rounding will always be one less than n. Similarly, 1 - c approaches zero, so the product of that with finite n approaches zero as well. @mcr0yal